# How can I merge two terminal windows in OS X lion?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I accidentally split a tabbed terminal up into two windows and I can't figure out how to join it again. Google tells me that I should drag it until it gets translucent on some other version of OS X but that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You have to select *View » Show Tab Bar* if it's not shown (possible if your window has only a single tab).

[image]

Then drag all tab headers (just below the window title bar) straight up or down — not sideways — to initiate a drag of a tab across window bounds. Now you get the translucent "drag visual".

[image]

Drag this to the other window, and the dragged tab will attach.

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can always select *Window » Merge All Windows* from the menu.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Terminal --> Windows -->"Merge All Windows"

[image: Screenshot of Terminal - Windows]

Comment: add inline pics by copying to clipboard then paste in any blank part of post window.

Comment: "All" != "two"...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to merge Terminal windows by using the top-level menu. Select Window → Merge All Windows.

Another way to achieve this without using the mouse is by adding a custom keyboard shortcut in System Preferences:

1. Open System Preferences, Keyboard, Shortcuts tab ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dRJ2.png))
2. Select App Shortcuts and press the + button
3. For the Application, choose Terminal.app from the list
4. For the Menu Title, type this text exactly: `Merge All Windows`
5. Choose whatever Keyboard Shortcut you want and press Add

Pro Tip: Start by selecting the Terminal window you want the others to merge into, then use the Merge All Windows function.

Comment: This is only correct if you have exactly two terminal windows open. In every other case "two" is different to "all".